# Exporting a query per row to csv in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, export

I have a `users` table that has an `id`, `first_name`, and `last_name`.

I also have a `messages` table that has a `user_id`, and `text`.

How do I export a user's messages to a CSV file *for each user*?

I can do it for one user:

```
COPY (SELECT text FROM messages WHERE user_id = "my user id") to "Firstname_Lastname.csv" DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

but postgres doesn't seem to have a for loop or anything? I did some googling and stumbled into `LATERAL` but could not get that to work...

Comment: SQL does not have a `LOOP`.  Postgres does though you will need to create a function to use it. See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS).

Answer (score 0):

Using Adrian's link and a lot of reading and cursing at my screen I hacked something together:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION export()
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  myuser RECORD;
  filename TEXT;
BEGIN
  FOR myuser IN SELECT id,first_name,last_name FROM users LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'user %', myuser;
    EXECUTE $$SELECT '/home/me/' || $1 || '_' || $2 || '.csv'$$ INTO filename USING myuser.first_name, myuser.last_name;
    RAISE NOTICE 'filename %', filename;
    EXECUTE $$COPY (SELECT text FROM messages WHERE user_id = '$$ || myuser.id || $$') TO '$$ || filename || $$' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER$$;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN 1;
END;
$$
```

It's quite a mess and is not idiomatic at all I'm sure. But it worked for me.